# Gitlab Runner use multiple Tags

Tags: gitlab, cicd, runner

is it possible to use multiple tags in one job like the example of Gitlab docs

job:
tags:
- runnerA
- runnerB

For me that config ends up with error "This job is stuck because you don't have any active runners online or available with any of these tags assigned to them".

We only use shared runners and I can find the tags assigned to runners

What I try is to archive is that one Job triggers two runners and the runners are working on different Servers.

Greetings

Answer (score 6):

The job is stuck because your runner needs to have all tags that are declared.  So a runner would need both `runnerA` and `runnerB` to process the job.

What may help you is the using `parallel` keyword with different tags.  This is defined in the docs here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#select-different-runner-tags-for-each-parallel-matrix-job

An example would be

```yaml
job:
  stage: somestage
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - RUNNER: runnerA
      - RUNNER: runnerB
  tags:
    - ${RUNNER}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case I used brackets to specify all the tags that I had registered the runner with.

```
Short-Unit-Tests:
  stage: Short-Unit-Tests
  script:
    - '& "$env:NUNIT_PATH" $CI_PROJECT_DIR\Project_PartialTest.nunit /xml=project-nunit-result.xml /config:Release /exclude:LongTest'
  tags: [SeverA, powershell, serviceuser]
```